# How to extract user information from github using their email address?

Tags: python, git, github

If I have the email address of some users and I want to extract their information from GitHub account. how I can do this using Python.I found this (https://help.github.com/articles/searching-users/) but how it can help me in extracting user information.

Answer (score 1):

You can either lookup how to web scrape information or try using the [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/) for user emails.

Comment: I want to search users based on their email address. Is it possible to search user by email address in GitHub??

Answer (score 1):

I know that retrieving user data using their e-mail is possible using the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/), which should return a JSON item with the user's information. I believe most of the tutorials for using the API use Ruby, though I see no reason why the same general principles wouldn't carry over to Python.
Otherwise, if you choose to use a web scraper instead, I'd recommend using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this. This ain't exactly the solution you might want , but this will work for you. In this code we have the **Username** not the **Email-Id** as input. The API is given in the code . But then to connect you need access token ( Similar to password ) . So you can create your own **Personal Token** . Here is the link to it :- https://github.com/settings/tokens . So now you have all the details and then you can play around with loops and all stuffs and extract whatever information you want.

P.S. :- If this solution doesn't meet your requirements , you can follow this link :- https://developer.github.com/v3/users/emails/  and do some changes accordingly in API

---

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'https://api.github.com/users/'

while True:
    user = raw_input('Enter user_name : ')
    if len(user) < 1 : break
    serviceurl += user +'?'
    access_token = "f6f02691c1d45293156ac5a2b7b324ed4fb9d2b4"
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'access_token': access_token})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    #print data
    js = json.loads(str(data))

    print json.dumps(js, indent=4)

    """for i in js:
        print i 
    print js["email"]"""
```